# Differentiable planes with finite roots

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

When I think about polynomials with the domain of complex numbers, I usually visualize a differentiable plane. The fundamental theorem of algebra implies that any polynomial has exactly roots equal to its degree with the domain of complex numbers, however if the graph can be represented as a plane, it seems that there can exist infinite solutions for some polynomials of finite degree. Take a look at $x^2 + 1$. This link provides a nice visual of what I am trying to represent with words, and presents this graph along the complex plane:
http://thescienceexplorer.com/universe/watch-imaginary-numbers-are-real.
$f(x) = x^2 + 1$ is equal to 0 for infinite points? This does not make sense.

Comment: No, when you move to the complex number system, you find precisely the *two* roots $\pm i$. I do not have the patience to watch all these videos, but I imagine from the picture that you're confusing the $2$-dimensional graph (which in some way represents the graph of the complex-valued function of complex numbers) with its intersection with the horizontal plane at position $0$ — which is the two points $\pm i$.

Comment: You would need 4 dimensions to actually graph the complex function. I believe it's graphing the real part only of $f(z)$. I still don't see how you're seeing infinitely many solutions. As I said, you have to look at the $0$-level, where there are precisely two points.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ahhh, I think I found where I was confused. This graph only plots the real part of the complex image. At these other points, where the graph intersects with the horizontal plane, the real part of $f(x + i\cdot y)$ is 0, however the imaginary part is not. And the only points where both the real and imaginary parts are 0 would be $\pm i$. Would this be accurate? You could make a second graph that would plot the imaginary part, and the intersection of where the two equal $0$ would be $\pm i$.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly correct. If you take $(x+iy)^2+1 = (x^2-y^2+1)+(2xy)i$, you need both $xy=0$ and $x^2-y^2+1=0$. Maybe I never saw the picture you were looking at. You have to make your question a lot more specific; you can't expect us to watch all those videos and know what you mean.